# Online Kotlin Compiler: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, kotlin

When I taking String input using **readLine()** method in kotlin using an online compiler officially provided by Jetbrains it gives me an exception today.
Here is screenshot?

[image: Output of Kotlin Compiler]

I also tried taking input using **scanner class** but it also does not works.

I am a beginner and practice kotlin basics using this compiler but its works fine till yesterday but i wonder why it not works today? Is there some error in my code or compiler bug?

Comment: This usually means that there is no console connected, so readLine() has no input to read from.

Comment: What can we do now to rid from that problem? @MarkRotteveel

Comment: My guess is that the online compiler doesn't support input, so you simply cannot do it like this. Install Kotlin locally and use that instead.

Comment: Kotlin playground doesn't provide a console input. If you want to try out things like that, I'd suggest using a Kotlin scratch file on Intellij IDEA IDE. Example provided in this old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754382/kotlin-scratch-file-android-studio-readline/62015494#62015494) of mine.